# Merge/join two objects based on a common key (push? splice?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, lodash

I've been trying using `push` and `splice`, etc. without success. I hope you could give me a clue (or two) to make it work. Below my problem, which doesn't seem so hard... :(

I have 2 objects:

**Object #1:**

```
houses:      [ { _id: 1,
                 KLLS: '72797-194155',
                 date : '01/01/1984'},

               { _id: 2,
                 KLLS: '84773-949399',
                 date : '01/01/1984'}
             ]
```

**Object #2:**

```
works:       [ { _id: 27,
                 KLLS: '72797-194155',
                 stuff : 'some stuff'},

               { _id: 28,
                 KLLS: '72797-194155', // Note that KLLS key is the same as id:27
                 stuff : 'some stuff'},

               { _id: 29,
                 KLLS: '84773-949399',
                 stuff : 'some stuff'},

               { _id: 30,
                 KLLS: '84773-949399', // Note that KLLS key is the same as id:29
                 stuff : 'some stuff'},

]
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
[ { _id: 1,
    KLLS: '72797-194155',
    date : '01/01/1984',
    stuff: 
         [ { _id: 27,
             KLLS: '72797-194155',
             stuff : 'some stuff'},

           { _id: 28,
             KLLS: '72797-194155',
             stuff : 'some stuff'}
         ]
   },

  { _id: 2,
    KLLS: '84773-949399',
    date : '01/01/1984',
    stuff: 
         [ { _id: 27,
             KLLS: '72797-194155',
             stuff : 'some stuff'},

           { _id: 28,
             KLLS: '72797-194155',
             stuff : 'some stuff'}
         ]}
]
```

Actually I'm at this point (using Lodash):

```
for(var i = 0; i < houses.length; i++) {

      // get the KLLS key for each house[i]
      var klls = houses[i].KLLS

     // retrieve the works corresponding to KLLS key for house[i]
     var trvx = _.filter(works, ['KLLS', klls])

    // Merge the two to get the wanted output...
    --> Whatever I try here, nothing works...
        even using splice or push...

}
```

Do you have any clue to get me on track?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```js
var a = [{
    _id: 1,
    KLLS: '72797-194155',
    date: '01/01/1984'
  },

  {
    _id: 2,
    KLLS: '84773-949399',
    date: '01/01/1984'
  }
]
var b = [{
    _id: 27,
    KLLS: '72797-194155',
    stuff: 'some stuff'
  },

  {
    _id: 28,
    KLLS: '72797-194155', // Note that KLLS key is the same as id:27
    stuff: 'some stuff'
  },

  {
    _id: 29,
    KLLS: '84773-949399',
    stuff: 'some stuff'
  },

  {
    _id: 30,
    KLLS: '84773-949399', // Note that KLLS key is the same as id:29
    stuff: 'some stuff'
  },

]
var newobj = []

var n = a.map(function(el) {
  var temp = []
  b.map(function(el2) {
    if (el.KLLS === el2.KLLS) {
      temp.push(el2)
    }
  })
  el.stuffs = temp
  newobj.push(el)
})

console.log(newobj)
```

Comment: Hello, It **almost** work :-).  Indeed the code needs to `push` items with b._id:27 **and** b._id:28 into a._id:1 (see my original message for a complete example). Whereas your code snippet inserts only b._id:28... Do you have any idea how to fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: @nerotulip Updated!. Consider accepting and upvoting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It'd be a pity having lodash and not using any of its handy methods to get to a solution.

Being `houses` the JSON labeled as 'houses' and `works` the JSON labeled 'works', you could do as follows to get your solution:

```
var res = _.reduce(houses, function (memo, house) {
    return memo.concat(_.extend({}, house, {
        stuff: _.filter(works, {KLLS :house.KLLS})
    }));
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

The idea is to `reduce` the `houses` array to a new array of houses `extended` with the works done on them.

I preferred to create a new object instead of modifying the originals so that the function could be as `pure` as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Concat the arrays, group them by KLLS, and then reduce each group array to produce the required object:

```js
function combine(arr1, arr2) {
  return _(arr1)
    .concat(arr2) // concat the 2nd array
    .groupBy('KLLS') // group the items by KLLS
    .map(function(group) {
      return group.reduce(function(result, obj) {
        if (obj.date) { // if it's an object with date, merge it with current result and return
          return _.merge(result, obj);
        }

        result.stuff.push(obj);
        return result;
      }, { stuff: [] }); // initial value is an object with stuff array
    })
    .value(); // end the chain
}

var houses = [{
  _id: 1,
  KLLS: '72797-194155',
  date: '01/01/1984'
}, {
  _id: 2,
  KLLS: '84773-949399',
  date: '01/01/1984'
}];

var works = [{
    _id: 27,
    KLLS: '72797-194155',
    stuff: 'some stuff'
  },

  {
    _id: 28,
    KLLS: '72797-194155',
    stuff: 'some stuff'
  },

  {
    _id: 29,
    KLLS: '84773-949399',
    stuff: 'some stuff'
  },

  {
    _id: 30,
    KLLS: '84773-949399',
    stuff: 'some stuff'
  },
];

var result = combine(houses, works);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```